# Finding the minimum length of multiple lists

Tags: python, list, min

I have three lists of different lengths.

For example

```
List1 is of length 40
List2 is of length 42
List3 is of length 47
```

How can I use the Python inbuilt `min()` or any other method to find the list with the minimum length?

I tried:

```
 min(len([List1,List2,List3]))
```

but I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to apply `len()` to each list separately:

```
shortest_length = min(len(List1), len(List2), len(List3))
```

If you already have a sequence of the lists, you could use the [`map()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
list_of_lists = [List1, List2, List3]
shortest_length = min(map(len, list_of_lists))  # map function
shortest_length = min(len(l) for l in list_of_lists)  # generator expr
```

To find the shortest list, not the shortest length, use the `key` argument:

```
list_of_lists = [List1, List2, List3]
shortest_list = min(list_of_lists, key=len)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use generator expression

```
min(len(i) for i in [List1,List2,List3])
```